# CSS – Height Percentage Not Working

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I'm making a responsive site and I have a section whose content will change (ranging from 1-150 characters in length). I want to give its parent (`.lie`) a fixed height & width so that I can center `p` inside it.

I know that percentage heights rely on the fixed heights of their parent but all my `div`'s parents have fixed heights. In Google's dev tools, `394px` works perfectly fine but switching it to `85.097192224622%` (`394px / 463px * 100%`) doesn't.

HTML:

```
<body>
  <main>
    <div class="pg-lie">
      <div class="lie">
        <p>content</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </main>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
body {
  height: 710px / 763px * 100%;

  main {
    height: 463px / 710px * 100%;

    .pg-lie {
      height: 394px / 463px * 100%;

      .lie {
        height: 100%;

        p {
          height: 100%;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to vertically center the `p` in `.pg-lie`. [Given your current code](http://codepen.io/daneden/pen/QwBdVV), one problem is that the `div.lie` inside `.pg-lie` has no CSS rules, so its height it defaulting to `auto`, which is whatever the height of the content of the `p` is.

You can pretty reliably vertically center content with one of a few techniques these days, even without knowing the height of the container(s). Check out these articles:

- [Solved by Flexbox: Vertical Centering](http://philipwalton.github.io/solved-by-flexbox/demos/vertical-centering/)
- [CSS Tricks: Centering in The Unknown](https://css-tricks.com/centering-in-the-unknown/)

Comment: My bad, I forgot to put in that `.lie` had a height of 100%. I did some tinkering and I think my problem was that the height of `html` wasn't defined (thought it was implied, whoops). 

Thank you for the resources though!